# How to conditionally add Blazor Component's Template?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm using a third party blazor component that receives a template, but I'm making a wrapper for that component that will also have a template property.

If someone use my wrapper with the template, it should pass the template, but if not, it should use the default template of the component.

What I tried is adding an if, but it doesn't work

```
@if (ItemTemplate != null)
    <ItemTemplate Context="Data">
            @ItemTemplate(Data)        
    </ItemTemplate>
}
```

It gives me an error

> Unrecognized child content inside component 'TelerikDropDownList'. The component 'TelerikDropDownList' accepts child content through the following top-level items: 'ValueTemplate', 'HeaderTemplate', 'FooterTemplate', 'ItemTemplate'

But if I add it the If inside `ItemTemplate`

```
<ItemTemplate Context="Data">
    @if (ItemTemplate != null)
    {
        @ItemTemplate(Data)
    }
</ItemTemplate>
```

It will render nothing, because the template content is empty.

How can I add `ItemTemplate` conditionally or use the default value of the components `ItemTemplate`?

**Observation**: I'm using Telerik, but this question should be generic for any component with templates

Comment: @enet But I'm asking this for any component that uses templates, not only Components of Telerik. This question is about Blazor Templates, not Telerik Components

Comment: Not to worry...He knows that as well.

Comment: @enet do you know the answer?

Comment: I can't say before I try to answer it...This is not that simple

Answer (score 4):

Consider moving the check out of the component declaration.
Here is an example. Let's assume you have two components: `InnerComponent` and `WrapperComponent`. Your code should look like this in the WrapperComponent:

```
@if(CustomTemplate == null)
{
   <InnerComponent />
}
else
{
    <InnerComponent>
        <ItemTemplate>@ItemTemplate</ItemTemplate>
    </InnerComponent>
}
```

Comment: If I have a very big component, I will need to replicate all the logic inside the if and the else and the only difference will the the template? I don't think this is good. Also, if you have more than one blazor template, you will have multiple if else if statements and will be so much complex

Comment: Alternatively, you can do that in the code - assigning the actual `ItemTemplate` property to a value in code. That will keep the markup clean

Comment: Correct answer, but looks kind of bad to do that when you component have alot of properties or more than one template. Hope on the future of blazor, they add some way to do this easier. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Vencovsky, I've been looking for a way to eliminate the concern you've brought up in your first comment above, and I came up with this (this is the `WrapperComponent`):

    <InnerComponent DefaultTemplate="CustomTemplate" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CustomTemplate { get; set; } = new InnerComponent().DefaultTemplate;
}

As you can see, this is a hack (I don't like this part: `new InnerComponent().DefaultTemplate;`)

Comment: @Artak That looks better, I'm trying to implement this, but because I'm using generics and third party library, I'm not being able to do that. Thanks any way, great answer!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Artak Just a question, have you test this `new InnerComponent().DefaultTemplate` ? I made it work, but it's giving me a very weird error. Is it possible to instantiate a component class?

Comment: Yes, I did test that and it's totally fine do that do. The only side effect (which is why I referred to it as a `hack`) is that you instantiate a component only to read a property for it. If you end up using that approach to avoid instantiating the `InnerComponent` again and again to get the DefaultTemplate, I would store that in a static field once only and refer to it. Not sure what error you're referring to as I don't get it.

Comment: Just came here to say a few things. Alot of times when triyng this `hack` to get the default template, I just get alot of errors and need to go back to `if else`. It's sad that it doesn't have a good way to do it. If you have 2 templates, its ok to do `if else`, but if you have 3 or more, it's very bad

Comment: You should file an issue for this in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore repo.

Comment: Hi. I can see this ticket is a bit old right now - but I am in the very same situation as described here. Have anyone found a good way to deal with this? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Artak Looks like an issue was opened and closed here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27924 Then re-opened a year later here: https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7459

Comment: @MattSanders you're right. The ask is there and it's a known pain point currently. There are, however, so many more pressing issues...